# Connect HID Omnikey 3121 to Citrix via Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04, card-reader

I want to know how I can use my HID Omnikey 3121 to pass its information on to a citrix-session.
I am working on Citrix-client and I have to logon to a site using a smartcard.
Ubuntu finds the cardreader and even the card itself.
However when I am in the Citrix-session, I can't see the cardreader.
This is what I get:

```
$ opensc-tool --list-readers
# Detected readers (pcsc)
Nr.  Card  Features  Name
0    Yes             OMNIKEY AG CardMan 3121 00 00

anton@anton-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ pcsc_scan
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: OMNIKEY AG CardMan 3121 00 00
 
Mon Jun 22 12:58:35 2020
 Reader 0: OMNIKEY AG CardMan 3121 00 00
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card inserted, 
  ATR: 3B FD 18 00 FF 81 31 FE 45 43 49 42 47 55 5A 49 4A 32 41 30 38 31 58

ATR: 3B FD 18 00 FF 81 31 FE 45 43 49 42 47 55 5A 49 4A 32 41 30 38 31 58
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = FD, Y(1): 1111, K: 13 (historical bytes)
  TA(1) = 18 --> Fi=372, Di=12, 31 cycles/ETU
    129032 bits/s at 4 MHz, fMax for Fi = 5 MHz => 161290 bits/s
  TB(1) = 00 --> VPP is not electrically connected
  TC(1) = FF --> Extra guard time: 255 (special value)
  TD(1) = 81 --> Y(i+1) = 1000, Protocol T = 1 
-----
  TD(2) = 31 --> Y(i+1) = 0011, Protocol T = 1 
-----
  TA(3) = FE --> IFSC: 254
  TB(3) = 45 --> Block Waiting Integer: 4 - Character Waiting Integer: 5
+ Historical bytes: 43 49 42 47 55 5A 49 4A 32 41 30 38 31
  Category indicator byte: 43 (proprietary format)
+ TCK = 58 (correct checksum)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B FD 18 00 FF 81 31 FE 45 43 49 42 47 55 5A 49 4A 32 41 30 38 31 58
    Caregiver card for Dutch Medical System called UZI
    (Unieke Zorgverlener Identificatie, Caring Unique Identification)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on (Ubuntu based) elementary OS and this is what worked for me:

```bsh
sudo apt install libpcsclite-dev
```

Then I downloaded and unzipped the driver from https://www.hidglobal.com/drivers/30476. Within the directory of the unzipped driver, use

```bsh
sudo ./install
```

You may need to install some other libraries, but the install script delivers helpful error messages.

Comment: updated driver URL is https://www.hidglobal.mx/drivers/29738, the address avobe is outdated